# Pandas Data frames and sorting values

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a difficult time with writing this hw assignment, and am not sure where I messed up. I have tried several things, and believe my issue lies in the sort_values or maybe in the groupby command.

The issue is that I want to only display graph data from the year 2007. (using pandas and plotly in jupyternotebook for my class). I have the graph I want *mostly* but cannot get it to display the data correctly. It simply isn't filtering out the years, or taking data from specific dates as requested.

```
  import pandas as pd
  import plotly.express as px
  df = pd.read_csv('Data/Country_Data.csv')

  print(df.shape)
  df.head(2)
  df_Q1 = df.query("year == '2007'")

  print(df_Q1.shape)
  df_Q1.head()
```

This is where the issue begins, because it prints a table with only header information. As in it prints all the column names, but none of the data for them, and then later on it displays a graph of what I assume is the most recent death data rather than the year 2007 as specified.

Comment: There is no provided input, no `sort_values` or `groupby` in the code and no error. I don't think we have enough details to help you

Comment: @James Complete guess, but there would be an issue here if the year were stored as an `int` rather than as a `str`. In this case, the query would come up empty as you observed

Comment: can you provide us your dataframe or the result of your `df.head`

Comment: Please provide outpit of `df.info()`, I guess it's what @BenGrossmann said; `year` column is not `str`.

Comment: By inspection I think you can try removing the single-quote around 2007, like this `df.query("year == 2007")`. I myself am more familiar with the following operation `df_Q1 = df[df['year']==2007]`. If you still have problem, please update your question with the result from running the following codes #1 `print(df.head())` #2 `print(df.dtypes)` #3 `print(df_Q1.head())`